# Who limit the CPU usage inside a task?

Tags: task, scheduled-tasks, cpu, infinite-loop

I'm programming some audio plugin inside an environment called Kontakt.
I see that CPU usage is limited if I try some fancy task.

For example, usually a infinite loop should eat all CPU:

```
index := 1
while(index > 0)
    message(index)
    inc(index)
end while
```

instead I see that CPU for that task is limited to 40%, and I can use the rest of the tools as well.

My question is: why? Who limits the CPU usage of that task? Is Kontakt that will limit the amount? Just curious...

Comment: If you are on a multi-core processor you can never use 100% CPU with one thread. Also it looks like Kontakt has [CPU overload protection](http://impactsoundworks.com/optimizing-your-kontakt-workflow-part-2/)

Comment: So basically, every process once used eat "100%" of CPU: it is just that usually are short (ms) that I don't see the 100% indicator on meter. But use as CPU as can for the time it needs (more or less). Right?